# Django: Is there a way to use "Extends" for a Div container that I can then add elements inside?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm making a website using Django.
I created a `<div>` container class to keep the content of my webpages standardized:

```
 <div class="container">  
    <div class="content">
      </div>
 </div>
```

I need this div class because its styling interacts with the navbar element I created.  I am looking for a way to use `extends` such that I can **add elements** **inside** the div container after I `extend` or `include` it in my new html page:

```
      <div class="container">  
                <div class="content">   
     <p> 
     </p>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

Is there a way to do this with Django without repeating code every time I make a new html doc?

Comment: Define a block inside the div and you can override in the new template

Comment: Hi Mohamed! Thanks for your quick reply. Could you give me an example of how? (First time writing with html/css)